# docker compose environment variable not setting the variable inside Dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm building my app for local development using `docker-compose.yaml`, using the two `Dockerfiles` - one for app (WordPress), and another for nginx. Since this is a specific app, that is built using Jenkins pipeline, I cannot change the Dockerfiles, but I would like to be able to have the same environment to test on locally as I have on the staging and production servers.

The php part works but nginx fails. The `Dockerfile` for nginx looks like this:

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY scripts/docker-nginx-entrypoint.sh /docker-nginx-entrypoint.sh
COPY ./config/nginx.conf /opt/nginx.conf
COPY ./config/nginx.conf.prd /opt/nginx.conf.prd

COPY --from=DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP /var/www/html/ /var/www/html/

CMD ["/bin/bash","/docker-nginx-entrypoint.sh"]
```

The `DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP` part fails with

> ERROR: Service 'nginx' failed to build: invalid from flag value DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

In my `docker-compose.yaml` for the nginx part I have

```
nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.static
    container_name: web-service
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP=app-admin"
      - "DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_NGINX=web-service"
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - 8090:80
```

I thought that setting the `environment` in the compose file would be enough, and that this will be used (the `app-admin` is the `container_name` of the php part with WordPress).

In my Jenkins pipeline scripts, these names are used to build the app and static images manually (using `docker build -t DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP -f Dockerfile.php`), and then the names are set to `env` like

```
echo -e "DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP=$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP" >>env
```

### EDIT

Like the answer suggested I've tried with adding `args` under `build` key

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.static
  args:
    - "DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP=app-admin"
```

Then in my `Dockerfile` I've added

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY scripts/docker-nginx-entrypoint.sh /docker-nginx-entrypoint.sh
COPY ./config/nginx.conf /opt/nginx.conf
COPY ./config/nginx.conf.prd /opt/nginx.conf.prd

ARG DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP

COPY --from=$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP /var/www/html/ /var/www/html/

CMD ["/bin/bash","/docker-nginx-entrypoint.sh"]
```

But I still get the error. I've tried with `${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP}`, but that doesn't help.

The odd thing is that adding `RUN echo $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP`, when I run this, I can see

```
Step 6/8 : RUN echo $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP
 ---> Running in 0801fcd5b77f
app-admin
```

But it's not recognized in the `COPY` command. How come?

### EDIT 2

So it turns out I cannot do this:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34482

Because the `--from` expects the image name (which I'm trying to pass to it from the previously build service but in my case it's dynamic). This works in the Jenkins since I'm doing a `docker build` command, and the variables are available in the bash script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COPY --from` does not support variables, but `FROM` does.

the following example uses multi-stage build, to help you extract whatever you need from the first image.

```
ARG DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP=php:7.3
FROM ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP} as php-image
FROM nginx:latest

COPY scripts/docker-nginx-entrypoint.sh /docker-nginx-entrypoint.sh
COPY ./config/nginx.conf /opt/nginx.conf
COPY ./config/nginx.conf.prd /opt/nginx.conf.prd

COPY --from=php-image /var/www/html/ /var/www/html/

CMD ["/bin/bash","/docker-nginx-entrypoint.sh"]
```

an almost similar example sits in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

Comment: This seems to provide the image name correctly, I don't think that the previous stage was set, so I'll need to look into this a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: your image is built from the last base image you specified in the multistage dockerfile, in this case - only from the nginx image. the previous stages are only there so you can `COPY --from` them, as we did. thanx and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For that, you must use `ARG` in the Dockerfile.

> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

`environment` in docker-compose.yml is not available when you're building.

> https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment

You can use arg in the docker-compose.yml too:

> https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args

Comment: I've added it as `args` under `build` key in the compose file, and I've added `ARG DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP` after `FROM` in my `Dockerfile`. When I do `RUN echo ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP}` I can see the desired output `app-admin`, but I still get an error when I have `COPY --from=${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_PHP} /var/www/html/ /var/www/html/` (tried also without `{}` still get the same result). Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: yep, that's a known issue: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2155 and https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34482